# Unable to create dataframe on the S3 file from aws

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark

With below code I am trying to read a file file from S3 aws and loading it into a dataframe.

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest
import com.databricks.spark.avro._


val credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("mykey", "mysecreteKey")
val s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
val s3Object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("bucket", "home/ubuntu/file_1463718615376_0.avro"))
val myData= scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(s3Object.getObjectContent()).mkString
val dfData = sqlContext.read.avro(myData)
```

I am able to do the same with file stored locally on my machine.

```
scala> val visitorData = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(s3Objectlv.getObjectContent()).mkString
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
        at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:182)
        at scala.io.BufferedSource$$anonfun$iter$1$$anonfun$apply$mcI$sp$1.apply$mcI$sp(BufferedSource.scala:38)
        at scala.io.Codec.wrap(Codec.scala:68)
        at scala.io.BufferedSource$$anonfun$iter$1.apply(BufferedSource.scala:38)
        at scala.io.BufferedSource$$anonfun$iter$1.apply(BufferedSource.scala:38)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.next(Iterator.scala:162)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$17.hasNext(Iterator.scala:511)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
        at scala.io.Source.hasNext(Source.scala:226)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.io.Source.foreach(Source.scala:178)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.addString(TraversableOnce.scala:320)
        at scala.io.Source.addString(Source.scala:178)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.mkString(TraversableOnce.scala:286)
        at scala.io.Source.mkString(Source.scala:178)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.mkString(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
        at scala.io.Source.mkString(Source.scala:178)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.mkString(TraversableOnce.scala:290)
        at scala.io.Source.mkString(Source.scala:178)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:63)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:68)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:70)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:72)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:74)
```

..........................

Comment: Are you sure `home/ubuntu/file_1463718615376_0.avro` is the path to your filename on S3? Sounds unlikely. Probably a typo.

Comment: `s3Object: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object = S3Object [key=home/ubuntu/file_1463718615376_0.avro,bucket=bucket]` I got after executing `val s3Object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("bucket", "home/ubuntu/file_1463718615376_0.avro"))` I shorten the file name for convenient

Comment: What does `S3Object` return? Do you see the bucket values?

Comment: Its returning `S3Object [key=home/ubuntu/20160520043017_append/part.task_file_1463718615376_0.avro,bucket=bucket]`

Comment: I would use this [method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getObject(com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest,%20java.io.File)) to save directly in file and then  let avro read and import the file, also you can easily see if the content of the file is as expected or not, compare to the stream